# sudo access to specific folder

Tags: macos

On OS X Mavericks, I want to install few files without prompting user for sudo password. (Folder where i am trying to install require root access because it is present at / location). I can do this by modifying "sudoer" file and disable sudo password but this is unsafe and open up security risk.

Is there any way I can provide sudo access only a particular folder? So when I try to write to this folder, sudo password prompt is not visible to user.

(All above task are done through command line)

Answer (score 3):

Don't modify the sudoers file. It isn't necessary. I think what you mean is *"is there anyway I can alter ownership and permissions so sudo isn't required?"* Yes. You can modify the folder's permissions and ownership settings using **Terminal.** Note, you will have to use **sudo** to do so and the command must be run by an administrator.

```
sudo chown -R $UID:staff /path/to/folder; chmod -R 755 /path/to/folder; exit
```

Substitute "/path/to/folder" with the proper path. The "chown" command changes ownership of the directory to you (and it's subfolders, using the -R option). The "chmod" command sets the folder's permissions to readable/executable by everyone and writable by the owner (you) only.

Comment: That's what i am trying to avoid. While writing to a specific folder, i don't want any type of password to be prompt. I am trying to perform a silent installation and it's purpose is defeated if any (admin) password need to be entered.

Comment: @iamMobile the admin password is only needed once - to run the command. After that, you won't need it again. You wouldn't be able to change the sudoers file without an admin password, either, btw.

Comment: @iamMobile Being able to do this with *no* password prompt at all would be a massive security hole in OS X.

Comment: @AndrewMedico yes, it would defeat the whole purpose of the UNIX based permissions and ownership.